# Compound literals with pointers

Tags: c

To pass a 2d array to a function with the array inline, I can do the following:

```
void print_arr2(int (*arr)[3], size_t size);

print_arr2((int[2][3]) {{1,2,3}, {3,6,9}}, 2);
print_arr2((int[][3]) {{1,2,3}, {3,6,9}}, 2);
```

However, the following notation doesn't seem to be supported or I am entering it in incorrectly:

```
print_arr2((int(*)[3]) {{1,2,3}, {3,6,9}}, 2); // pointer to int [3]
```

Is this last format not supported, or what's the reason that that fails in trying to use a compound literal for it?

Comment: Remember the compound literal initialization `{{1,2,3}, {3,6,9}}` is describing an ARRAY, not a pointer. The pointer would need `NULL` or a valid address where an array is located in memory. The initializer is not an object stored in memory. Essentially what you are doing is equivalent to `int *p = {1, 2, 3}`;`.

Comment: In the last case there is no array to point to. If you use either of the previous to *define* the array, then you can cast it e.g. `print_arr2((int(*)[3]) (int[][3]) { ... }, 2);` will work.

Comment: @dxiv pretty cool, thank you: `print_arr2((int(*)[3])(int[2][3]) {{1,2,3}, {3,6,9}}, 2);`

Comment: Please post the declaration of `print_arr2()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(int(*)[3]) {{1,2,3}, {3,6,9}}` creates a compound literal that is a pointer to an array of three `int` and then attempts to initialize it with two lists of three `int`. A pointer must be initialized with an address.

A solution is to create a 2×3 array, which will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, yielding a pointer to an array of three `int`: `(int [2][3]) {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 6, 9}}`.